# What can I do to repair my metal gazebo frame?

Tags: repair, metal-roof

My friend gave my his old gazebo frame as the canvas has worn out and replacing it was equivalent to the cost of getting a new one. It is 10x10 feet.

I bought a medium duty green brown tarp to cover the top of it. I used twine to affix it to the frame and it held up to the wind and water. There ended up being an issue with the latter. Light rains collected since the tarp was near impossible to keep taught. At least I thought it was taught enough.

Some heavy rains came over the last couple of days and I went out to check to see how it was holding up during just in case. I checked *way* too late.

[image: old worn out frame]

I figure it is impossible to try and remove this with the hopes of putting it back together. Where the "roof" meets the rest of the frame is also bent in.

Any ideas on what I can do to try and fix this? Even if I could get almost good I should be able to improve the tarp taught-ness now and even put some holes in it on purpose to mitigate future water issues.

Comment: I'm not hot on the tags used but am not here enough to have a good idea what to use.

Comment: You'll probably spend more fixing the junky thing than you'd spend to get something not quite as junky to replace it. The way it came to you should be a clue...

Comment: There _was_ nothing wrong with it. The issue was my ignorance of its ability to hold water. Now perhaps it is not worth the effort but this is not for parties and what not. Its just something I wanted to use to keep the sun off my ginger sking.